# [Rspec/Capybara]How can I detect page's content while it's loading by Visit method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, automated-tests

I'm quite new to Rspec/Capybara.

I want to test how fast I can load my main content in my page before the page is fully loaded by visit method.

If I do this

```
starts = Time.now
visit "/"
pp Time.now - starts ******(this will start after visit "/" fully loaded)
test_time = Time.now - starts
test_time.should < 10
```

The output in console would be 10.xxxx (10 seconds) because it does pp method after it finishes loading my home page (fully load all contents in page).

**Is there anyway I can do something like this?**

```
starts = Time.now
visit "/" do (visit and do something while it is loading)
  break if page.has_content("Main content appeared now !!") (Detect if the page has content "Main content appeared now !!" then break and stop loading page
end
pp Time.now - starts
test_time = Time.now - starts
test_time.should < 10
```

and the result would be something like 2.12342 (because we stop visit to stop loading when it detects content

Or any way else I can detect content while page is loading.

Comment: It would be helpful perhaps if you could clear up exactly what it is that you're trying to test. What actions are you performing, and what are you trying to assert? Also, showing a bit of code helps.

Comment: I did edit my question, sorry for my bad question at first.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Your question is now much clearer with code, so I've voted to reopen it. Remember that StackOverflow questions typically receive a positive response if you include code of what you've tried or are attempting.

Comment: That said, my answer to this question would be that you probably can't accomplish what you're seeking out using Capybara. There is a lot of functionality baked into Capybara that makes sure all scripts and content are loaded before it does anything. I would not fight against that.

Comment: What's the difference between "main content" and all content? Are you talking about before and after Javascript?

Comment: When I call visit method, it will wait until all content in the page is loaded then go next. I want to test only how fast my main content showing up ,but visit method does wait until every on page is loaded. So, I don't know how to do that. Is there someway ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with capybara. Try using Selenium-Webdriver, though Selenium does not wait until page is completely loaded.

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to url
while driver.find_elements(:id, 'element_id').size > 0
    sleep 0.1
end
test_time = Time.now - starts
p "#{test_time} seconds"
driver.quit
expect(test_time).to be < 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with capybara also

#spec_helpers.rb

`Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
 Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
 end`